# Array printed as a string in csv

Tags: python, arrays, string, csv, int

I need to save some data to a .csv file. I have 8 ports and the time trying to be saved to the file the problem is in the formatting comes out to look like 
['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '00:38:10'].  How would i get this without the brackets and ''.  I think it has to do with how the time is saved in a string but not sure.  Here is some of the sample code

```
def save_array():
    t = utctime.t()
    a = data.get_data()
    atime = np.append([a],[t])
    return atime
def t():
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow() 
    return dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: a little unclear on what you are asking. Do you want the format to be       '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '00:38:10'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list` (what you are calling array) can be turned into a string delimited by `,`s by using the `str.join()` function.

```
>>> my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '00:38:10']
>>> ",".join(my_list)
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,00:38:10'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what i wanted

Comment: Glad I could help! If you think this answers your question, please mark it as accepted :)